Why is there an asterisk next to the close vote total? E.g. Close (1*)
I just noticed that there's now an asterisk next to the close vote totals. What does it mean?


Arrived here after a web search for the same question but for 'reopen' vote count. I initially assumed the asterisk meant my vote didn't count for some reason (perhaps due to insufficient rep or something like that).

It means that you've voted to close that specific question.
The same thing applies to posts on which you've cast reopen, delete, or undelete votes.

This appears to be a recent change to the platform.
I would guess that the reasoning is to inform you, at a glance, that you've already voted on that question, without needing to take the time to click to open the dialog (which would show "You have already voted to close this question") or hover over the "Close" link to show the tooltip (which would say "You voted to close as '[reason here]'. 2 more votes from other users are needed to close this question.").  It's especially useful for delete votes, which were previously very easy to accidentally retract if you didn't remember that you'd already voted to delete that specific post.

"reasoning is to inform you" -- a pity they (yet again) forgot to inform the users that they've released such feature and what it really means. Oh well...

@DanMašek It's just the usual. Feature gets released, then SE take hours to mention what they've released. Same with this which was five hours after I asked whether it's a feature or a bug

Now that I know, I'm very grateful for the change. The UI could definitely be further improved, though.

This is a nice feature, but I think it would be nice if the same could also apply to the flag button

I wonder what's worse, @DanMašek , release a feature that's not bad, but not telling anyone, or release a feature, tell everyone, they hate it, so you continue to push that release onto the users more.

@ThomA Hard to say, but the first seems easy to mitigate. You don't need a press release for every small thing, but some publicly accessible (and easily reached, advertised) changelog or release notes, even autogenerated one would be useful. It's gonna be "power" users that will notice such changes, so they'd generally know where to check what's going on, before having to ask on meta.

We were soooo close this time... things happened, people got busy at the wrong time. We might get it right one day, hang in there.

@Carrott Yeah, shit happens, but it's hardly the first time, and I ask "how does a 15 year old company get to this situation"? What's so badly broken? I seems like utter chaos in there from the outside. Noone really seems to know what others are doing, things get released accidentally, QA seems to be a swearword...

@DanMašek I'd say we're trying to make things happen faster than previous years. It felt like it used to take months for a small change to be released and communicated. Which meant that small bugs and feature requests were few and far between. We're trying to be more flexible and experiment with process changes (which lets us do things like a Community Asks Sprint) but that comes with hitting a few bumps along the way. At least some fixes are going out and we'll work on the timing of comms.

@ThomA  ...I don't know you man, same time!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFQuba-XvC8

This was released earlier today, reference to this answer on the original request.

We made changes to address this issue.

We added an asterisk (*) to the count if you were the one to vote on that post. For example: Delete (1*). There's already an existing hover tooltip that explains you have voted on this.

This change applies to votes to delete, close, undelete, and reopen.





Great new feature! Some might consider this a very minor change, and I can understand their logic. But it's a small change that is very useful.
